# Facebook API: Send authentication detail from Javascript SDK to PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have integrated Facebook's PHP SDK in codeIgniter and able to login with it. But some articles suggested that using Javascript SDK for client side authentication provides better performance.
But if I am able to successfully authenticate a user with JS SDK then how would I pass this info to PHP SDK so that server side code can get Graph details of the logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken, a session is done with cookies. So when you send them to a php page after authentication, a cookie that was set by the javascript sdk will be sent automatically with all the normal headers to your server, and the PHP SDK should pick up on the fact that they are a logged in fb user. Play around with that and see what you get.